# Azure Logic Apps can't programmatically build And / Or Condition using ASP.Net SDK

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm programmatically building a Condition in a Logic App. If the user selects Or, I use the Or Condition. If the user selects And, I use the And Condition.

I can get Or to work by itself. I can also get And to work by itself.

```
public class Expression
        {
            public Or[] or { get; set; }
        }


public class Expression
        {
            public And[] and { get; set; }
        }
```

When I try to use the Expression class below, I get a "Condition has 2 top level properties. Only 1 is allowed." error.

```
public class Expression
    {
        public Or[] or { get; set; }
        public And[] and { get; set; }
    }
```

If I set one to null, I get the error. If I set one to an empty array, I get the error.

**UPDATE 1**

Here is the Logic App code view in Azure.

```
"expression": {
                "and": 
                 [
                    {
                      "contains": [
                          "@outputs('Compose_3')",
                          "foo"
                     ]
                    },
                    {
                       "contains": [
                           "@outputs('Compose_3')",
                           "bar"
                     ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
```

Does anyone know how to get this to work? Am I missing something simple here? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you building your own action/connection item?  Are you able to provide a little more context because in the true sense, this is not something that looks directly related to Logic Apps and conditions.

Comment: I'm building out the JSON schema for the Logic App API. I can't pass both an And Condition and an Or Condition. It has to be one or the other. If I leave one as null or one as an empty array, I get the error. There has to be a way of programmatically creating a Condition as either And or Or using the Expression object. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working. When you Serialize the JSON, use "IgnoreNullValues = true". This will ignore the null value this is present when you set the And or Or value in your Expression object. ReplaceFirst simply adds a "$" to the word "schema" on the first occurrence.

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true, IgnoreNullValues = true};
            string jsonString = ReplaceFirst(JsonSerializer.Serialize(myApp, options), "schema", "$schema").Replace("_else", "else").Replace("_foreach", "foreach");

string ReplaceFirst(string text, string search, string replace)
        {
            int pos = text.IndexOf(search);
            if (pos < 0)
            {
                return text;
            }
            return text.Substring(0, pos) + replace + text.Substring(pos + search.Length);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic App has a default **AND / OR** and other ***conditional operators***. If you want to add a custom condition you can use an Azure Function. In the Azure Function, you can implement your custom requirement and it is the correct environment to implement your thoughts of logic.

You can include the Azure Function in a logic app to perform your task. Refer  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions)

Or we have another option to implement a custom requirement which is [**Logic App Custom Connector**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/create-logic-apps-connector). Please have a look  [here](https://bizbrains.com/blog/azure-custom-connector-for-logic-apps/)

Comment: Thanks @Delliganesh-MT! I'm building out the JSON schema for the Logic App API. My Expression object has both Or[] and And[]. If I leave one as null or one as an empty array, I get the error. There has to be a way to programmatically do this. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't find anything related to that to achieve this using programmatically.  The better way is to use the azure functions in logic app.